# Pull list from tibble for tidy data

Tags: r, tibble

I am trying to deal with data in which I have a tibble, within which I have a list of tibbles for certain observations. I would like to extract the data from this list so as to have some tidy data.

Here is a short example:

```
data_1 <- tibble(year = c(2015, 2016), 
                 pop = c(100, 200))

data_2 <- tibble(year = c(2015, 2016), 
                 pop = c(300, 500))

data_combined <- list(data_1, data_2)

x <- tibble(country = (c('1', '2')), 
            data = data_combined)

print(x)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  country data            
  <chr>   <list>          
1 1       <tibble [2 x 2]>
2 2       <tibble [2 x 2]>

print(x$data)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   year   pop
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2015   100
2  2016   200

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   year   pop
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2015   300
2  2016   500
```

What I would like is the following tidy data format (I don't mind if its a data.frame or a tibble):

```
  country year pop
        1 2015 100
        1 2016 200
        2 2015 300
        2 2016 500
```

I assume the easiest way to do this is to return the list that is `y$data`, keeping the country field, and call: `do.call(rbind)` on that. I don't know how to do the first part.

Perhaps I am getting this all wrong and having data in this format is useful. If that is the case, and there is a way for effectively handling tibbles with lists of tibbles within them, then I would welcome any information on that.

The context for all this is that I am trying to deal with data generated by this API: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eia/eia.pdf. The API is limited to only generate 100 rows for each call. I assume that for this reason the authors have used this data format to allow one to get more data for each row. If you want to understand a general example see below:

```
#load libraries
library("eia")
library("dplyr")

#set API key for the session
eia_set_key(key = "[YOUR_KEY_HERE]")

#select a variable of interest by looking through: eia_cats() -> eia_child_cats(2134384)
anth_production <- eia_cats(2134515) %>% #select data for Anthracite (as a list)
  .$childseries %>% #subset the childseries element of the list
  filter(units == "Million Metric Tons of Oil Equivalent") %>% #filter to only have MMTOe
  .$series_id #subset the IDs to use in the eia_series() call 

#call the eia_series() function of the API
anth_production_tibble <- eia_series(id = anth_production)
```

`anth_production_tibble` now appears in the same format that i generated above in my reproducible example. I will write a function to deal with the 100 row limit at a later point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
librar(dplyr)
x %>%
   unnest(data)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  country  year   pop
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1        2015   100
#2 1        2016   200
#3 2        2015   300
#4 2        2016   500
```